# SOLVED: How to combine multiple font faces and variables into ggplot title?

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, plot, environment-variables

This one has me stumped everyone!

I am trying to create a title for ggplot that is bold, but also has a bolditalic character, and also evaluates a variable.

In the code below, I illustrate an example of plotting randomly generated normally distributed data. The mean, coded by the variable `mu`, takes the value of `5`. Ideally, the plot title, encoded by `fig_title`, should look like **normal, *mu* = 5**, but I am getting, **normal, *mu* =** 5.

Also, any suggestions on how to bold the entire string (as opposed to the individual components)?

Many thanks!

~ jat

```
# The mean
mu <- 5

# Randomly distributed values
y <- rnorm(100, mean=mu)

# My attempt at the plot title.
fig_title <- as.expression(bquote(bold('normal, ')~bolditalic('mu')~bold('=')~bold(.(mu))))

# Associated ggplot
ggplot(data.table(Y=y), aes(x=Y)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  ggtitle(fig_title)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. It works when you convert `mu` to character. 
I simplified a little bit by grouping the last bold block.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
# The mean
mu <- 5

# Randomly distributed values
y <- rnorm(100, mean=mu)

# My attempt at the plot title.

fig_title <- as.expression(bquote(bold('normal, ')~bolditalic('mu')~bold('='~.(as.character(mu)))))

# Associated ggplot
ggplot(data.table(Y=y), aes(x=Y)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    ggtitle(fig_title)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The package [ggtext](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) has `element_markdown()` that allows you to render markdown code into any `ggplot2` element.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(data.table)

mu <- 5

y <- rnorm(100, mean = mu)

fig_title <- 'normal, *mu* = 5'

ggplot(data.table(Y = y), aes(x = Y)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  ggtitle(fig_title) +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]

The cool thing about `ggtext` is that it allows you a lot more styling, for example, changing part of the text's colour.

```
fig_title <- 'normal, <span style="color:red">*mu*</span> = 5'

ggplot(data.table(Y = y), aes(x = Y)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  ggtitle(fig_title) +
  theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]